# How to pass <img> value on click?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a project where there are tiles of different pictures and I want to pass the value to another page when an image is clicked on. Since `<img>` doesn't have a *value* attribute, I tried to wrap an `<a>` tag around the image as follows, although it does the job, the format of the image is messed up. Is there a better way to do this that doesn't mess with the format of the image? Thank you for your help.

```html
<a href="results.inc.php?value=gpu" onclick="post">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="" class="cardImg">
</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean with the format is messed up? You could also just add an `onclick` trigger to the image that will fire a specific function and sends a value to the other functions.

Comment: @tacoshy the front end was made by another developer and he used bootstrap to make the images displayed as tiles. When I wrap the anchor tag around the image, the format of the picture and the tiles are changed and they don't look the same as the other tiles.
edit: sorry for noob question, I don't know a lot about html/css or js. Do I have to use Javascript for that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, the most "harmless" way to do it would be JavaScript, adding a custom attribute to the image for the value you want it to pass in the `onClick` method.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
               var allCards = document.querySelectorAll(".cardImg");
               for(i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
                   var value = allCards[i].getAttribute("data-card-value");
                   allCards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                       document.location.href = "results.inc.php?value=" + value;
                   });
               }
            });
```

```css
.cardImg {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" data-card-value="gpu" alt="" class="cardImg">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this after I watch some JS tutorial XP.